# Qooxdoo xhr.js cannot be located

Tags: qooxdoo

The current project i am working on consists of 2 parts. 1 part is a 
qooxdoo app. And the other is a html file that will be rendered in the 
browser widget of qooxdoo.

I recently had to make some changes to the second part (not touching 
qooxdoo).

After i copied over the files i needed to connect the Qx app to the html 
page. Then it gave me some errors.
I taught if i rebuild, they might go away (they did not).
I get the following error:

LOG: 003045 qx.core.Init: Load runtime: 3044ms
SCRIPT5: The system cannot locate the resource specified.
Xhr.js, line 375 character 9

I have looked and the file is located where it should be.

Does anyone has any idea how to fix this or what is causing it?

Comment: Duplicate of mailing list posting http://qooxdoo.678.n2.nabble.com/Re-Can-t-find-Xhr-js-after-upgrade-td7581849.html

Comment: Yes, i also posted it on the mailing list. But i have found the solution. I will add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was rather silly, i placed one too many parenthesis and that caused the error. I had trouble finding it since the 2 where very unrelated.